# What was the Collector doing?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War*,

> Thanos uses the Reality Stone to create a false reality where he is defeated. As this reality concludes, the Collector begins clapping oddly.

Was there some significance to this, or is it just Benicio Del Toro being weird?

Comment: I assume he did it because he approved of the outcome? That's typically why people clap. Could have been Thanos controlled sarcasm though I suppose.

Comment: Thanos was taking a piss, basicly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "Collector" that we and the Guardians saw

> wasn't real. He was a part of the illusion that Thanos was projecting. When Gamora believes she killed Thanos and begins to cry over his dead body

he sees it as touching and, like the audience of any spectacular-heartfelt performance, begins to applaud with the projection of the Collector, even having him call it "magnificent".